# Recursive elements in Schema : Mongoose modelling

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Any idea how to model a Tree document in Mongoose Schema?

```
var TreeSchema = new Schema({
    "Non-leafNode": {
        "children": [
            {
                "type": "NodeElement"
            }
        ]
    },
    "NodeElement": {
        // one of them is required. not both.
        "elem": {
            "type": "LeafNode"
        },
        "elem2": {
            "type": "Non-leafNode"
        }
    },
    "LeafNode": {}
});
```

How could one model this? The entire Tree is one document (ideally).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/0yUVXNyprx8:

> By design, it might work. There's no tests for this. I have `Schema#add` in there for this purpose, to produce recursive references:

```
var Tasks = new Schema();
Tasks.add({
   title     : String
 , subtasks  : [Tasks]
});
```

So you need to construct the recursion step by step.

Comment: How would you populate that? In case you want to get all the information of all descendants of all tasks

Comment: It's all in a single Mongo document, so it's already populated