# Nested elements in mongoose modelling

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nested, data-modeling

I have to create a database in this format:

[image]

I have tried to do it like this :

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
,   Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var categorySchema = new Schema({
    _id:              String,
    subcategory:      {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Subcategory"
    },
    id:               String,
    name:             String,
    page_description: String,
    page_title:       String,
    parent_category:  String,
    c_showInMenu:     Boolean
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

And I did the same for every subcategory, but I named them "Subcategory" and "SubsubCategory". I'm pretty much a newbie, I've read the documentation on mongoose and I've also followed an online course. I feel like I know something, but I don't understand it properly or that my logic behind it is wrong.

Also, I've managed to find this about recursive elements in Schemas, but I don't fully understand it and I don't know how to implement it to my database: [Recursive elements in Schema : Mongoose modelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825773/recursive-elements-in-schema-mongoose-modelling)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to create a model so that I will be able to use the information from the database in my ejs file.
For example to use it as :

<p> <%= Category.page_description %> </p>

Comment: As per my observation, you already have data and you want to create the model for it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and collection image.

Here's what you are doing wrong.

- You don't need to declare **_id** field, it's auto-generated.
- Keep the column names same as they are in the given collection image.

This should be your schema declaration. Note that, this schema is for the whole collection and not just for categories array.

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
        Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

    var mainSchema = new Schema({
        categories: [ {
        id:               String,
        image:             String,
        name:             String,
        page_description: String,
        page_title:       String,
        parent_category_id:  String,
        c_showInMenu:     Boolean
      }]
    });
```

This is just an example of the schema, please add necessary changes to it.