# Populating across multiple levels doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I've got blog model which has multiple comments which have multiple replies. I want to go through all of them and with my code I've been only able to access only the first 2 layers.

This is in my DB as Comment objects:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9770fc0147e40f1c53aab8"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5c97734db48ab60f6139ffa3") ], "author" : ObjectId("5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5"), "text" : "comment", "__v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c97734db48ab60f6139ffa3"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5c977a169f98a8106dc0dc5c") ], "text" : "2", "__v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c977a169f98a8106dc0dc5c"), "comments" : [ ], "text" : "3", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c977b3b3a5bb410ce7e0e70"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5c977b533a5bb410ce7e0e71") ], "author" : ObjectId("5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5"), "text" : "1", "__v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c977b533a5bb410ce7e0e71"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5c977b6f3a5bb410ce7e0e73") ], "author" : ObjectId("5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5"), "text" : "2", "__v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c977b6f3a5bb410ce7e0e73"), "comments" : [ ], "author" : ObjectId("5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5"), "text" : "3", "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment Schema:

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User"
    },
    text: String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Comment"
    }]
});
```

Blog object:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c9770ee0147e40f1c53aab6"), "comments" : [ ObjectId("5c9770fc0147e40f1c53aab8"), ObjectId("5c977b3b3a5bb410ce7e0e70") ], "title" : "title", "image" : "", "text" : "text", "author" : ObjectId("5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5"), "date" : ISODate("2019-03-24T11:58:38.227Z"), "__v" : 2 }
```

Blog Schema:

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    date: ({type: Date, default: Date.now}),
    text: String,
    image: String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }]
})
```

Here's my route

```
router.get("/:id",function(req,res){
    Blog.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate("author")
    .populate({
        path: "comments",
        model: "Comment",
        populate: {
            path: "comments",
            model: "Comment"
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err,blog){
        if (err) console.log(err);

        res.render("../views/blogs/show",{blog: blog});
    })
});
```

And here is what I get when I print blog:

```
{ comments: [ { comments: [Array], _id: 5c97734db48ab60f6139ffa3, text: '2', __v: 1 } ], _id: 5c9770fc0147e40f1c53aab8, author: 5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5, text: 'comment', __v: 1 },{ comments: [ { comments: [Array], _id: 5c977b533a5bb410ce7e0e71, author: 5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5, text: '2', __v: 1 } ], _id: 5c977b3b3a5bb410ce7e0e70, author: 5c9770e60147e40f1c53aab5, text: '1', __v: 1 }
```

How do I populate all of the nested arrays of comment objects?

Answer (score 1):

There [isn't a direct support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38102443/3340702) for retrieving a potentially infinite nested object references (Comment->Comment->Comment->...). This is obvious because of performance reasons.

A mongoose plugin for [deeply populating nested moodels](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate/) exists so you can do it easily using a code like this:

```
const deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
blogSchema.plugin(deepPopulate, {}); //<- {} empty options

// ...

Blog.findById(req.params.id)
.populate('author')
.deepPopulate('comments.user')
.exec(function (err, blog) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.render("../views/blogs/show",{blog: blog});
});
```

Please read the [readme](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate/blob/master/README.md) for many useful information about the plugin and keep in mind that deep populating [can be really inefficient](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate/issues/68) and that you can *limit* the deep population using plugin's options.