# Limit mongoose document nested depth

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have setup a nested mongoose document, I want set the max nested depth of subcategory to 5, I tried to add a 'depth' field in the categorySchema, but still got some problem when I update the category. Is there any way to limit the mongoose document nested depth in coding?

The schema is like this:

```
const categorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    categoryId: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    subcategoryIds: [{ type: String }],
  }
)

categorySchema.virtual('subcategories', {
  ref: 'Category',
  localField: 'subcategoryIds',
  foreignField: 'categoryId',
  autopopulate: true,
})
```

Comment: You mention that you "got some problem when I update the category". Can you elaborate on that? For clarification, is it correct that your actual depth of refrence is higher than 5 and what you want to achieve is to only show the subcategories that are within a depth of 5 from the categories that you are finding?

Comment: @abondoa The problem is when I update one category to depth of 5, others category depends on it would become depth of 6. I want to control the actual depth of 5, not only when I'm finding.

Comment: So it is more of a restraint on the validaity of a category instance? E.g. if you create a new category and in that category add a sub-category reference to another category that already has sub-categories of depth 5, the new cateogry should be invalid and cannot be saved because it would lead to a depth of 6. Correct?

Comment: @abondoa maybe it's quite hard to implement, for now I just limit the update of categories (e.g: depth = 3) can only add subcategories whose depth is lower than the them (e.g: depth < 3)

Comment: @abondoa the new category should be invalid and cannot be saved, yes. But when I update categoryA, add a category (depth of 4), categoryA becomes depth of 5, and maybe categoryB's subcategory includes categoryA, so some how categoryB would become 6

Comment: I am not aware of any out-of-the-box solution in mongoose for this. You might need to develop some custom validator on the Schema. As an alternative, have you considered to store sub-categories as sub-documents instead of using references? It might make this validation easier.

Comment: @abondoa The subcategories is same as categories, just like a folder includes another folder, so I don't want to store it separately, but I can try to develop some custom validator. Thanks for your answers, it's very helpful.

Comment: You can still use the same schema and make it recursive (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825773/recursive-elements-in-schema-mongoose-modelling). However, your use-case might be such that it is not feasible. Happy to help :)