# how to use promises in forEach loops node?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, foreach, async-await

I have a page that displays user contacts. it retrieves an array of _ids from a specific user and the should iterate over these arrays to get corresponding contact information. However I get stuck with my async operations. In the current situation it resolves after the firs contactinformation was pushed to the invitationsFromFriendsData array. If I put the resolve outside the forEach loop, it resolves instantly without adding any contactinformation to the array. What am I doing wrong?

```
  exports.contactBoard = async (req, res) => {
    const username = req.params.username;
    const doc = await User.findOne({'username': username}).exec();

    const friendFiller = async () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
          doc.invitationsFromFriends.forEach (async element => {
          const doc1 = await User.findById(element).exec()
            doc.invitationsFromFriendsData.push(doc1.username)
            resolve('gelukt')
        });
        })};

    const send = async () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        res.status(200).json({
          message:"retrieved user contacts",
          contacts: doc
          })
          console.log("Nu verzenden")
          resolve ('gelukt')
        })

    };

    const verzend = async() => {
      let first = await friendFiller();
      console.log('Ik wacht op het vullen')
      let second = await send();
    }

    verzend();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await an array of promises.

```js
const friendFiller = async () => {
   const friends = await Promise.all(doc.invitationsFromFriends.map((id) => User.findById(element).exec()));
   friends.forEach(() => {
      doc.invitationsFromFriendsData.push(doc1.username);
   })
}
```

Having said that I think Mongoose can perform "joins" on your behalf with [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) which I expect is more efficient as it'll issue a single DB query for all the friends.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think populatie would work even if in a model User i would reference to a User?

Comment: I think you can model recursive schemas with schema.add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825773/recursive-elements-in-schema-mongoose-modelling I don’t know for sure if populate works with this but I don’t see any reason why it wouldn’t.